Are instrumental norms supposed to be taken literally?
If we have an instrumental norm such as, "If one wants to be correct, one ought to conclude in alignment with the evidence," is it supposed to be taken literally? That is, does it mean "Concluding in alignment with the evidence is useful for being correct," or does it refer to an actual imperative to do what is most effective in reaching your desire to be correct?

"Concluding in alignment with the evidence is useful for being correct" - pretty sure it's just this

The form you have given is an implication between two imperatives (norms), so it is not itself an imperative (norm) but a declarative, that one norm implies the other. Of course, it is often implicit that the antecedent norm is binding, in which case such implications can serve as implicit norms. But that is their illocutionary effect, not literal meaning. In conditional imperatives proper, the antecedent is not a norm but a descriptive condition, as in "if you are at an intersection, turn right", and those are literally imperatives (norms).

by reading

If one wants to be correct, one ought to conclude in alignment with the evidence

as

If one wants to be correct, one must not conclude in disaligment/disaccord with the evidence

to mean not (only)

Concluding in alignment with the evidence is useful for being correct

but rather

Concluding in alignment with the evidence is necessary for being correct

so i guess there is an imperative

I don't understand why the necessity there would imply an ought?
